# Вызов конструктора из конструктора

Tags: java

Не могу понять, как это сделать, помогите кто знает.

Знаю что элементарно, но все же:

есть два конструктора, один конструктор (без аргументов) должен вызывать второй конструктор (с аргументом типа `int`).

```
public class MyInitTest {
    private String a;
    private double c;

    {
        a = "non-static initialization block ";
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    {
        c = 20.03652;
        System.out.println(c + a);
    }

    static private String string;
    static private int anInt;

    static {
        string = "Static block";
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    static {
        anInt = 6;
        System.out.println(anInt + "Static block");
    }
    public MyInitTest(){

    }
    public MyInitTest(int){

    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class Privet {

    public Privet(){
       this(1); // Этот конструктор вызывает конструктор с параметром
    }

    public Privet(int a){
       // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
public class MyInitTest{
    public MyInitTest() { 
        this(1);  // вызов второго конструктора
    }

    public MyInitTest(int i) { 
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: дааа опередили ))))

Answer (score 8):

Если нужно вызвать конструктор родительского класса, то

```
super(7);
```

если другой конструктор текущего класса, то

```
this(8);
```

Comment: @Nofate, даже не подумал, что оба конструктора могут быть в одном классе.